# Ruby mixins looking for a best practice

Tags: ruby, mixins

I'm writing Ruby Gem where I have `Connection` module for `Faraday` configuration

```
module Example
  module Connection
    private

    def connection
      Faraday.new(url: 'http://localhost:3000/api') do |conn|
        conn.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
        conn.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
        conn.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
        conn.use      Faraday::Response::ParseJson
        conn.use      FaradayMiddleware::RaiseHttpException
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Second module which makes API requests looks like this:

```
module Example
  module Request
    include Connection

    def get(uri)
      connection.get(uri).body
    end

    def post(url, attributes)
      response = connection.post(url) do |request|
        request.body = attributes.to_json
      end
    end

    def self.extended(base)
      base.include(InstanceMethods)
    end

    module InstanceMethods
      include Connection

      def put(url, attributes)
        response = connection.put(url) do |request|
          request.body = attributes.to_json
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Class `Cusomer` where I use `Request` looks like this:

```
module Example
  class Customer
    extend  Request

    attr_accessor :id, :name, :age

    def initialize(attrs)
      attrs.each do |key, value|
        instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
      end
    end

    def self.all
      customers = get('v1/customer')
      customers.map { |cust| new cust }
    end

    def save
      params = {
        id:   self.id,
        age:  self.age
        name: self.name,
      }

      put("v1/customers/#{self.id}", params)
    end
  end
end
```

So here you see in `Customer#all` class method I'm calling `Request#get`  method which is available because I extended `Request` in `Customer`. then I'm using self.extended method in `Request` module to be make `Request#put` available in `Customer` class, so I have question is this good approach to use mixins like this, or do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

Mixins are a strange beast. Best practices vary depending on who you talk to. As far as reuse goes, you've achieved that here with mixins, and you have a nice separation of concerns.

However, mixins are a form of inheritance (you can take a peek at `#ancestors`). I would challenge you saying that you shouldn't use inheritance here because a `Customer` doesn't have an "is-a" relationship with `Connection`. I would recommend you use composition instead (e.g. pass in `Connection/Request`) as it makes more sense to me in this case and has stronger encapsulation.

One guideline for writing mixins is to make everything end in "-able", so you would have `Enumerable`, `Sortable`, `Runnable`, `Callable`, etc. In this sense, mixins are generic extensions that provide some sort of helpers that are depending on a very specific interface (e.g. `Enumerable` depends on the class to implement `#each`).

You could also use mixins for cross-cutting concerns. For example, we've used mixins in the past in our background jobs so that we could add logging for example without having to touch the source code of the class. In this case, if a new job wants logging, then they just mixin the concern which is coupled to the framework and will inject itself properly.

My general rule of thumb is don't use them if you don't have to. They make understanding the code a lot more complicated in most cases

EDIT: Adding an example of composition. In order to maintain the interface you have above you'd need to have some sort of global connection state, so it may not make sense. Here's an alternative that uses composition

```
class CustomerConnection
  # CustomerConnection is composed of a Connection and retains isolation
  # of responsibilities. It also uses constructor injection (e.g. takes
  # its dependencies in the constructor) which means easy testing.
  def initialize(connection)
    @connection = connection
  end

  def all_customers
    @connection.get('v1/customers').map { |res| Customer.new(res) }
  end
end

connection = Connection.new
CustomerConnection.new(connection).all_customers
```

Comment: Thank you Josh for answer, but it little bit unclear what do you mean hear:  I would recommend you use composition instead (e.g. pass in Connection/Request) as it makes more sense to me in this case and has stronger encapsulation.

Comment: What Josh means is that you should create a Connection/Request class that is useable within your Customer class. When you instantiate your Customer you can pass in your Request class or you could instantiate a Request in your initializer for Customer. Personally I prefer doing something with composition b/c then I can test the individual objects easily.

Comment: Unflores can you please provide an example?

Comment: @user525717 I added an example. In order to retain the `Customer.all` interface you'd have to bind the connection to the class at some point (which is probably more effort than it's worth, so a mixin approach might just make things simpler)